# Какой знак нужен перед "не"? Тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Перед "не" тире или запятая: *"Люби не хочу"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно разное оформление: ***люби не хочу*** или ***люби – не хочу*** (запятая не ставится).

Варианты можно проверить по сочетанию ***бери не хочу***.  При этом нужно определить **грамматическую роль фразеологизма**, в соответствии с этим делается выбор и постановке тире между его частями.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_788

Сочетания «бери не хочу», «ешь не хочу», «пей не хочу» и т. п. обособляются или оформляются как отдельное предложение. Между частями сочетаний возможно тире.

Звери, забыв вековечные страхи, // С твердою верой, что всё по плечу, // Шкуры рванув на груди как рубахи, // Падают навзничь – **бери не хочу!** В. Высоцкий, Заповедник.

Весь мир только для твоего наслаждения создан... **бери – не хочу!** М. Арцыбашев, У последней черты.

**Хлеба – ешь не хочу**, брага не переводится, а хоть сыты живут, да всласть не едят, не то что по вашим местам. П. Мельников-Печерский, В лесах.

А здесь раздолье ― вон сколько парней по улицам шатается. **Бери не хочу.** Говорят, нахватали, сколько могли. [Андрей Волос. Сирийские розы // «Новый Мир», 1999]